# Delete a line from a text file by overwriting using arrays to store the lines of a text file

Tags: java, arrays, file

I need done in the most simplest way possible..... And where have I gone wrong here....

This is my code so far...

```
import java.io.*;
class test
{
public static void main()throws IOException
{
    FileReader f=new FileReader("g.txt");
    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(f);
    PrintWriter p=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("g.txt")));
    String ar[]=new String[5];
    String text;int i=0;
    while((text=in.readLine())!=null)
    {
        ar[i]=text;
        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    for(i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
    {
        if(ar[i].equals("the da vinci code"))
        {
            ar[i]=null;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int j=0;j<ar.length;j++)
    {
        System.out.println(ar[j]);
        p.println(ar[i]);
    }
    in.close();
    p.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way though better is to write to another file as you read from this, have a try -catch and close the file handles in the finally, use logging ...

```
package files;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;//growing array

class ReadFileRemoveLines// class test is a bad name
{
    public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException//need to follow the signature or cant start the program
{
    FileReader f=new FileReader("g.txt");
    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(f);

    ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>(5);//initial size if you expect so many lines or leave out the 5 ()
    String text;int i=0;
    while((text = in.readLine()) != null)//spaces between symbols help readability
    {
        //why not test test here
        if(!text.equals("the da vinci code")){
            ar.add(text);
        }
        ///i++;
    }
    /*
    i=0;
    for(i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
    {
        if(ar[i].equals("the da vinci code"))
        {
            ar[i]=null;
            break;
        }
    }*/
    in.close();
    PrintWriter p=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("g.txt")));
    for(int j=0;j<ar.size();j++)
    {
        System.out.println(ar.get(j));

        p.println(ar.get(j));//why are you printint of i loop is j
    }

    p.close();
}
}
```

Comment: also try an IDE to format your code and organize imports, thought its good to compile and run from command line to understand basics. IDE will also tell you helpful things like variables not being used (I have left i unused)

Answer (score 0):

Just making the underlying reference of that line `null` does not delete that line in that file.

1. You need to read the file completely.
2. Pick up the lines which you want and store them in a collection.
3. Rename or move that file(Create a backup just in case).
4. Write all the lines again with the same file name.